# Is there a way to limit the bandwidth of a current source?

Tags: current-source

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth of a current source so it acts as a voltage source(low impedance) above a certain frequency?
[image]

I want to shunt high frequencies away from the output of a folded cascode via the current source. Using a cap filter anywhere in the direct current path screws with the distortion figure because of the current transfer function so it needs to be done through the current source.

Comment: You're assuming that a current source will act as a voltage source when operating outside it's bandwidth. That might not be true depending on the current source's circuit. What bandwidth are you talking about? Without a specific circuit example this is impossible to answer.

Comment: It's for a folded cascode circuit. I want to shunt high frequencies away from the output of the cascode. If the frequency is not reflected by the current source then it shouldn't appear at the output. How can I make a bandwidth limited current source?

Comment: *It's for a folded cascode circuit* So **show the circuit**. *If the frequency is not reflected by the current source* Unclear what you mean. Describe it in current/voltage and/or impedance. *Reflections* is a word we use when dealing with transmission lines.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you would know what a folded cascode was. I updated the question.

Comment: How sharp do you want the cutoff to be? (eg. 20dB/decade)

Comment: *I thought you would know what a folded cascode was.* I do know what a folded cascode is. I have 25 years circuit design experience. But that's not the point. The point is that you should always include a schematic, no matter how trivial. Also, for a proper folded cascode, the "Current source" resistor would be a current source, not just a resistor. You could also draw a current source with a resistor in parallel.

Comment: Bro, I've stated clearly that I want the current source to perform an active function. Obviously this means that resistor is not actually a resistor. It even has "current source" labeled right next to it. Read between the lines. It should be obvious what I'm talking about if you know what a folded cascode is.

Comment: "How sharp do you want the cutoff to be?" I'm okay with a 5-10khz differential between the point where it starts to degrade and the cutoff point. I don't know how that translates into dB/decade.

Comment: I guess it would be better to say I want everything under 20khz to be at very high impedance. I'm okay with a gradual drop off until 25k-30khz.

Comment: Cutoff frequency is generally defined as the point where the signal drops by 3dB. What happens above that depends on the filter. A single pole RC low pass filter with cutoff at 20kHz will have ~5dB loss at 30kHz.

Comment: in this case he may be looking for closed loop gain < 1 instead of 1e6/f  , we cant tell

Answer (score 1):

There may be requirements to define Zout(f) in addition to transfer function (f).

[image]
[image]
By suppressing the feedback, you reduce the CC correction effects on higher frequency load signals.  This has a breakpoint > 50kHz.

Comment: I appreciate the alternative solution but is there a way to make the current source do the job instead? I really want to know how to make the current source high performance and bandwidth limited.

Comment: Use Cap across BC of current source instead

Comment: Can you show me an example? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: SHow your results

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/S5z8Mt5.png

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was originally doing. It maintains regulation past the corner frequency without hindrance though.

Comment: U2 looks very interesting.  Almost like a semiconductor triode?

Comment: It's an enhancement mosfet meant for current source duties.

Comment: It only attenuates the closed loop gain which might be quite large I still do not understand your real problem

Comment: The above picture I want none of the 40khz signal current to end up in V2 and all of the 20khz signal current to end up in V2. Since the current source is feeding a DC line it must shunt the 40khz current. Any caps over a few pf in the direct current path will cause distortion of the signal in V2. That's why I want the current source to act as a low impedance shunt above a certain frequency. In reality there will be a I/V resistor before V2, probably around 1k.